# Get the element from a function that was called inside the element's event

Tags: jquery

lets assume that I have the following ...

```
jQuery('#a').click(function(){
   myFunction();
});
function myFunction(){
  var me = jQuery(this);// this one gets the "window" object instead of "#a" element
}
```

How can I get the target element that initiated the event from `myFuncton` while I **cant** send `this` as parameter because its going to coast me to go back and re-check the whole site and change every function call arguments ...

Comment: why can't you send this? jscript is not strongly typed. So you can use this only where you need it. you can check for undefined values before each usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you could just do:

```
$('#a').click(myFunction); // then this in myFunction will be the '#a' element.
```

***Update**:*

If you need to do other thing in the callback other then myFunction, then you could try `.call()` or `.apply()` to execute a function with a given **this value**.

```
$('#a').click(function() {
    otherLogic();
    myFunction.call(this);
});
```

Comment: no sir, i'm sorry but this small demo dosent show the whole image ... the click event do alot of logic one of them is calling the `myFunction` function ...

Comment: your update is helpful .. thanks alot ... but i hope to find a way so i will not have to change all of the function calls ... thanks again

Comment: se my answer, you don't have to change all the function calls

Comment: i'm sorry sir but with your way i'll have to change every single place i call `myFunction()` to `myFunction.call(this)` right ?

Comment: no, you don't have to change it you can still call your function without arguments in other places, that's the cool thing about js been a loosely type language, the function signature are not strictly enforced

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jQuery('#a').click(function(){
   myFunction(this);
});

function myFunction(elem){
  var me = jQuery(elem);
}
```

You will get the current object that called the function in the elem as you passed it from the  click event

Comment: sir in my post i wrote that i cant do so because its going to coast me to go back and change the entire website where ever the `myFunction` is called ... thanks anyway sir

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#a').click(function(){
   myFunction(this);
});
function myFunction(sender){
  if (sender !=undefined)
   {
      var me = jQuery(sender);// and do other stuff
      //.....
   }
   //do your old stuff -- me will be logically out of scope
}
//this will not result in an error, sender will be undefined
// the code will be compatible backwards
myfunction();
```